# javafx. combobox column in tableview like a comboboxcolmn from .net with valuemember and displaymember

Tags: java, .net, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have two table at database:

```
City_table
id int(8)    | name varchar(250)

Person_table
id int(8)    | name varchar(250)    | id_in_city int(8)
```

And I want to display with possibility of editing Person_table at TableView, where column `id_in_city` will be represented as combobox column.

It's very easy at .net, there the comboboxcolumn have a `ValueMember` (in my case this is the data from the column "id" from City_table) and `DisplayMember` (the data from the column "name" from City_table) propertys. In comboboxcolumn of datagridview displayed names, but in source of data the id-s is stored.

How to organize the same functionality on javafx?

I need something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TreeTableViewEditDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<Employee>();
        treeTableView.setEditable(true);

        // Create column EmpNo (Data type of String).
        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> empNoCol //
                = new TreeTableColumn<Employee, String>("Emp No");

        // Gender Column
        TreeTableColumn<Employee, Gender> genderCol //
                = new TreeTableColumn<Employee, Gender>("Gender");
        genderCol.setMinWidth(90);

        // Add columns to TreeTable.
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(empNoCol, genderCol);

        // Data
        Employee empBoss = new Employee("E00", "M");

        Employee empSmith = new Employee("E01", "F");

        Employee empMcNeil = new Employee("E02", "M");

        // Root Item
        TreeItem<Employee> itemRoot = new TreeItem<Employee>(empBoss);
        TreeItem<Employee> itemSmith = new TreeItem<Employee>(empSmith);
        TreeItem<Employee> itemMcNeil = new TreeItem<Employee>(empMcNeil);

        itemRoot.getChildren().addAll(itemSmith, itemMcNeil);
        treeTableView.setRoot(itemRoot);

        // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
        // Get value from property of Employee.
        empNoCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("empNo"));

        // GENDER (COMBO BOX).
        genderCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, Gender>, //
        ObservableValue<Gender>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Gender> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, Gender> param) {
                TreeItem<Employee> treeItem = param.getValue();
                Employee emp = treeItem.getValue();
                // F,M
                String genderCode = emp.getGender();
                Gender gender = Gender.getByCode(genderCode);
                return new SimpleObjectProperty<Gender>(gender);
            }
        });
        ObservableList<Gender> genderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(//
                Gender.values());
        genderCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(genderList));

        // After user edit on cell, update to Model.
        genderCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Employee, Gender>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Employee, Gender> event) {
                TreeItem<Employee> item = event.getRowValue();
                Employee emp = item.getValue();
                Gender newGender = event.getNewValue();
                emp.setGender(newGender.getCode());
                System.out.println("Single column commit. new gender:" +newGender);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().add(treeTableView);

        stage.setTitle("TreeTableView (o7planning)");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

  public class Employee {

    private String empNo;
    private String gender;

    public Employee(String empNo, String gender) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(String empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

  }

  public enum Gender {
    FEMALE("F", "Famale"), MALE("M", "Male");

    private String code;
    private String text;

    private Gender(String code, String text) {
      this.code = code;
      this.text = text;
    }

    public String getCode() {
      return code;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return text;
    }

    public static Gender getByCode(String genderCode) {
      for (Gender g : Gender.values()) {
        if (g.code.equals(genderCode)) {
          return g;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.text;
    }
  }
}
```

But not enum... I need dynamically changeable (at runtime) "reference book" with Cities
In database table stores ID, not object of type Cities

Comment: Try to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html?

Comment: "Cell is rendered as a Label when not being edited, and as a ComboBox when in editing mode" and nothing more. In most examples from Oracle comboboxcell into comboboxcolumn displays its value. There is no division between the displayed value and the stored argument

Comment: Actually you can use `setId()` method for id as `ValueMember`.

Comment: Will not work.
When reading information from the table, will be loaded ids. How will the text names be displayed automatically instead of them?
How to edit the table of cities, with automatic change of the combobox?